# Insertion_Sort() implementation (Error), Python

Tags: python, indexing, implementation, insertion-sort

I have two version of the implementation of INSERTION SORT; I think **that are equivalent**, but **the second one returns a sorted list wrong.**
This is the first one:

```
def insertionSort(A):
for j in range(1,len(A)):

    key = A[j]
    i = j

    while i>0 and A[i-1]>key:
        A[i] = A[i-1]
        i -= 1

    A[i] = key
```

this is the second one:

```
def insertionSort(A):
    for j in range(1,len(A)):

        key = A[j]
        i = j-1

        while i>0 and A[i]>key:
            A[i+1] = A[i]
            i -= 1

        A[i+1] = key
```

I've tested these two algorithm with this C array

```
C = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
insertionSort(C)
print(C)
```

In the first case my array is correctly sorted; in the second case my result is:

> [54, 17, 20, 26, 31, 44, 55, 77, 93]

The second case comes from the pseudo code on my school book. **Why doesn't it work correctly?**

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel-- Hint loop at source code for bisect...  https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a correction of your second code:

```
def insertionSort(A):
    for j in range(1,len(A)):

        key = A[j]
        i = j-1

        while i>=0 and A[i]>key:
            A[i+1] = A[i]
            i -= 1

        A[i+1] = key
```

The difference lies in the `>=` towards `>` in the while loop. 
To understand, let's refer to the behaviour of the insertion sort. 
That sorting algorithm assumes that the array [0, j-1] is sorted and then places the element at the right place.

Now, lets assume that we wan't to sort `[4,3,2,0,5,6,7]` and we're now in that state:

```
A = [2, 3, 4, 0, 5,6,7]
```

The first three elements are in the right place and we need to put 0 in its right position (index 0). From i = 2 to i= 0, the condition `A[i] > key` is always true. So, we will do: A[3] = A[2], A[2] = A[1], A[1] = A[0].

Then we will leave the loop with `i = -1` and set `A[i+1] = A[0] = 0`.

In your previous version, the loop would stop at `i = 0` and the last instruction would do `A[0+1] = A[1] = 0`. It's why when you give `[2, 3, 4, 0, 5,6,7]` in the algorithm, it gives a bad result.